# Openlayers-3 wfs-t save coordinates displacement?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I'm using [openlayers-3](http://openlayers.org) in client side and geoserver in server side. I have a vector layer. I get this layer from geoserver as follow:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?&service=WFS&" +
           "version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=points:cinema" + 
           "&outputFormate=application/json";

var format = new ol.format.WFS();
source = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'proxy.cgi?url=' + encodeURIComponent(u),
    format: format
});

cinemaLyr = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Cynema',
    source: source
});
map.addLayer(cinemaLyr);
```

I get `cinemaLyr` correctly, I modify this layer and save it as follow:

```
var node = wfs.writeTransaction(null, [modifiedFeature], null, {
    featureType: "points:cinema",
    featureNS: "http://opengeo.org",
    srsName: "EPSG:4326"
});
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs";

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'proxy.cgi?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    method: 'POST',
    xmlData: s.serializeToString(node),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("Everything is fine");
    }
});
```

This code save the `modifiedFeature` on server, but its `coordinate` is displacement(`x` save as `y` in geoserver and vice versa).  In `Insert` and `Delete` it do correctly, Only in `Update` request displacement point coordinate. **How do I fix it?**

Comment: When you insert a point this occur(displacement point coordinate)?

Comment: In `Insert` and `Delete` it do correctly, Only in `Update` request displacement point coordinate.

Comment: Try indicating the `srsname` param in the request. See http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-wfs.html. It seems an issue with projection translation or a bug.

Comment: When I set url as `var url = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?&service=WFS&" +      "version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=points:cinema" + 
           "&srsName:EPSG4326&outputFormate=application/json"` It doesn't work

Comment: Projections and coordinate axis order problems are easier to handle with WFS 1.0.0. I would first try to change the vesion from 1.1.0 into 1.0.0. BTW you made typos at least in the comment, should be srsName=EPSG:4326, as well as outputFormat.

Comment: It works fine, But in reading features occur displacement point coordinate

Comment: You can only use WFS 1.1.0 for transactions, as it is hard coded in the `writeTransaction` method. You can however manually swap the coordinates of the updated features before you write the transaction, as described [here](http://webmappingtutorial.blogspot.hu/2015/08/swapping-coordinate-order-in-ol-3.html). Don't forget to clone the features first!

Comment: Sorry, did not notice it was OpenLayers 3.

Comment: [@Gabor Farkas](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/36475/gabor-farkas) its true. Can you get your comment as a response to I confirm it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GeoServer indeed tends to swap coordinates on several occasions when using WFS. I couldn't backtrack this phenomenon to its exact origin, only to this [post](https://viswaug.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/reversed-co-ordinate-axis-order-for-epsg4326-vs-crs84-when-requesting-wms-130-images/), where it is assumed, this confusion is created by the different axis orientation of EPSG:4326, and CRS:84, which are otherwise identical projections.

A possible workaround could be implemented on the client side, swapping the coordinates manually. I created a [blog post](http://webmappingtutorial.blogspot.com/2015/08/swapping-coordinate-order-in-ol-3.html) about it, but I copy the relevant code part here, if it is gone for some reasons:

```
var swappedFeature = modifiedFeature.clone();
swappedFeature.getGeometry().applyTransform(function (coords, coords2, stride) {
    for (var i=0;i<coords.length;i+=stride) {
        var y = coords[i];
        var x = coords[i+1];
        coords[i] = x;
        coords[i+1] = y;
    }
});
var node = wfs.writeTransaction(null, [swappedFeature], null, {
    featureType: "points:cinema",
    featureNS: "http://opengeo.org",
    srsName: "EPSG:4326"
});
```